# Express.js response to Angular CORS Error

Tags: angular

I want Express server side redirect angular page.
I run express at localhost:3000
angular at localhost:4200
when Express redirect to Angular localhost:4200 
I always get error

```
Failed to load http://localhost:4200/login: Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

how to let angular accept cors response?

Comment: Why do you want to redirect?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43407783/how-to-overcome-cors-from-angular-2-to-node-express

Comment: @ChatarSIngh  because when google auth expired i want to redirect to login page

Answer (score 5):

Install cors package in your server-side express code

```
npm install --save cors
```

Use that in your server.js or app.js file where you implement all logic of express.js

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

It enables the cross-origin functionality, where you can access the request from another domain

Comment: but I want to send response to angular

not send request to express

is this server side problen?

Comment: @luk https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500073/request-header-field-access-control-allow-headers-is-not-allowed-by-itself-in-pr  please check the link